# Changing color of overlay on preexisting image

Tags: image-editing, overlay

I am fairly new to graphic design and image editing, but I have a question. I have the following image that came with a website theme that I am playing around with.[image]

I like the image a lot, but I am wondering if there would be any way to change the overlay color to a different color of my choosing? I am fairly new to image manipulation, but have been learning, so any advise is greatly appreciated.

I am using GIMP 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RGB histogram shows that this is a colorized grayscale image. The Pointer tool shows that in the HSV model, the only difference between pixels is the V (value/lightness), Hue and Saturation remaining the same.

For a quick job, `Colors>Colorify` is your friend.

Possibly cleaner: add a transparent layer, set it to "color" mode (selector at top of layers list) and bucket fill with the color of your choice (knowing that the final result will be darker than the color you choose).

For extra control: `Color>Desaturate` to convert it back to grayscale, then use `Color>Map>Gradient map` to map the gray tones to a gradient (typically, a black-to-color one).

If you want more control, `Color>Desaturate` to convert it to grayscale fol

Comment: Wow. Colors>Colorize worked perfectly. It changes the photo immediately. Thank You!

How do you look at the RGB histogram of the photo?

Comment: `Windows>Dockable dialogs>Histogram`. It will show value, or individual R, G, B channels, or R+G+B on the same graph depending on what you select.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting the contrast so the lightest is as close to white as you can get and the darkest is closer to black. Then convert it to greyscale (or simply use a "desaturate tool" if available).

You can then set it to "overlay mode" and place a solid color layer under it, or you can play with any "colorization" tools the software might have.

Comment: I'm not at my office at the moment right now, but I think I understand what you are saying. I will give it a try in a bit and let you know.